# How to create nested macro in Boo

Tags: boo

I am creating nested macros in Boo, I wrote this program:

```
macro text:
  macro subMacro:
    text["Text"] = "Hello World"

  return [|
    block:  
      System.Console.WriteLine( "Hello World" );
  |]
```

But I am getting the error "Unknown Identifer: '**text**'" in the 3rd line of the code.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is likely to do with a missing import in the code where the macro is being called from.

If your macro is in a namespace named foo for example, you will need to add

```
import foo
```

At the top of the calling code.

A second issue you may run into once you fix this compiler issue is the error

"Unknown identifier 'block' (BCE0005)

To fix this, add a `.Body` after the quasi-quotation section like this:

```
import Boo.Lang.Compiler.Ast

macro text:
    macro subMacro:
        text["Text"] = "Hello world"

    return [|
        block:
            System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    |].Body
```

EDIT - IMHO macros are a bit of a dark art.  For more help, you should try the [boo mailing list](http://groups-beta.google.com/group/boolang?pli=1), or the excellent [DSLs in BOO](http://www.manning.com/rahien/)